# How to convert UIImages to 8-bit-color image on iphone ？

Tags: iphone, uiimage

I have some UIImages from a camera.  Is there any way to convert UIImages to 8-bit-color images, quickly and accurately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a `CGBitmapContext` and draw the image's `CGImage` to the bitmap context.